# Get only super class fields

Tags: scala, inheritance, extends, case-class

```
case class Person(name: String, 
                  override val age: Int, 
                  override val address: String
    ) extends Details(age, address)

class Details(val age: Int, val address: String)

val person = Person("Alex", 33, "Europe")

val details = person.asInstanceOf[Details] // ??? 
println(details) // I want only Details class fields
```

I have these 2 classes. In reality, both have a lot of fields. Somewhere, I need only field of superclass, taken from Person class.

There is a nice way to get only super class values and not mapping them field by field?

**I'm pretty sure I'll have some problems with json writes for class Details (which is not a case class and have not a singleton object, but this is another subject)*

Comment: Your `println(details)` is actually `println(details.toString)` and this `toString` implementation comes from the `class` of the `instance`. Here, the actual `class` of your `instance` is `Person`, so it will use that. This is exactl hwo inheritance works. Also, your class `Details` does not have any fields. You can check by creating an instance of `Details` by `val d = new Details(1, "Europe")`, you will not be able to access `d.age` or `d.address` as it does not have any field member.

Comment: maybe this works? `val details =  person.getClass.getSuperclass` ?

Comment: @Ben That will give you the run time super class of `Person`. What do you think can be done using run time class ?

Comment: @sarveshseri you're right, I updated my question. My idea with this inheritance was to avoid to duplicate fields in both classes, age and address to be defined only in super class, but I think I'm on a wrong way with that :d

Comment: @AlleXys can you post an example of what should be the expected output?

Comment: What does "get fields" mean? Just print their contents?

Comment: I want `details` object to have type `Details` and values from person (something like automapping), because later I need to write a json based on it. I'm asking if I can avoid creating a new object as: `val onlyDetails: Details = new Details(person.age, person.address)`

Comment: You still would need to duplicate the fields in the constructor and you won't win much with that pseudo abstraction over the case classes. You can rather have another case class `Details` and use that to abstract the repeated fields.

Comment: @sarveshseri I thought about getting the *class* fields (via reflection), like in the questions title (get only *class fields* of superclass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, then you might be asking me runtime polymorphism or dynamic method dispatch from java.
If so, you may have to create both the class and not case class

```
class Details( val age: Int,  val address: String)

 class Person(name: String,
                  override val age: Int,
                  override val  address: String
                 ) extends Details(age, address) {

}
```

Now create the object of person and reference to superclass (Details)

```
val detail:Details =  new Person("Alex", 33, "Europe")


println(detail.address)
println(detail.age)
```

This way you will be able to get the only `address` and `age`

Another way is like , why can't we create the `Details` a separate entity like:

```
case class Details(  age: Int,   address: String)

 case class Person(name: String,
                   details: Details
                 )


val detail =   Person("Alex", Details(10,"Europe") )
```

Output:

```
println(detail.details)

Details(10,Europe)
```

Comment: Because I have a mysql table with more than 80 columns and I tried to have an entity (or domain), I had this problem. So, my repository returns a class with 80 fields (exactly as the db table fields). To not modify it, I think I'll need to map manually the repo result in a new case class with Details as a nested class inside of Person (this will be the service job).

Comment: Yes, try always keeping the nested structure for grouped data, that way JSON parsing will be also easy for you.

Comment: I checked Amit answer because I found an issue in my logique and his response solve it. I need to compare previous value of class Person with the new value (db requests at every 30 seconds). But in Scala, seems that I can not compare 2 instance of a class (with `==` or `equals()`), so I need to map it in another case class with nested fields (nested objects) and then to compare the values. Awesome Scala :D I found I can override equals method, but I don't want it.

Comment: I don't need to check every field manually (`if new.field1 == old.field2 && new.field2 == old.field2 && ..` so on). In javascript, can do something like `class.fields.forEach(field => newClass[field] == oldClass[field])`. This is something of reflection in Scala and is too far from me right now :d

Comment: Yes that's correct, but eventually, you will get there with all scala syntactic sugar. Happy learning mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

I will post a solution that leverages scala macro system (old kind, not the newest introduced with Scala 3.0). It could be an overkill for you...

BTW, if you want to access to only parent values (for example for getting key, value pair), you can:

1. given a type tag, get all parents;
2. from them, extract all the accessors (vals);
3. for each val, get its value;
4. and finally returns a list with all accessors taken

So, I try to solve each point step by step.
First of all, we have to write the macro definition as:

```
object Macros {
  def accessors[T](element : T): String = macro MacrosImpl.accessors[T]
}

object MacrosImpl {
  def accessors[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Expr[String] = ...
}
```

for the first point, we can leverage the reflection macroprogramming API using `c.universe`:

```
import c.universe._
val weakType = weakTypeTag[T] //thanks to the WeakTypeTag typeclass
val parents = weakType.tpe.baseClasses
```

for the second point, we can iterate over the parent classes and then take only the public accessors:

```
val accessors = parents
      .map(weakType.tpe.baseType(_))
      .flatMap(_.members)
      .filter(_.isPublic)
      .filter(_.isMethod)
      .map(_.asMethod)
      .filter(_.isAccessor)
      .toSet
```

So, for example, if the we write `Macros.accessors[Details](person)`, `accessors` will yield `age` and `address`.

To take the value, we can leverage quasiqouting. So, first we take only the values name:

```
val names = accessors
      .map(_.fullName)
      .map(_.split("\\."))
      .map(_.reverse.head)
```

Then we convert them into a `TermName`:

```
val terms = names.map(TermName(_))
```

And finally, we convert each term to a key value tuple containing the val name and its value:

```
val accessorValues = terms
   .map(name => c.Expr[(String, Any)](q"(${name.toString}, ${element}.${name})"))
   .toSeq
```

The last step consist in convert a `Seq[Expr[(String, Any)]` into a `Expr[Seq[(String, Any)]`. A way to do that, could be leveraging recursion, `reify`, and `splicing` expression:

```
def seqToExprs(seq: Seq[Expr[(String, Any)]]): c.Expr[Seq[(String, Any)]] =
  seq.headOption match {
      case Some(head) => 
        c.universe.reify(
          Seq((head.splice._1, head.splice._2)) ++
          seqToExprs(seq.tail).splice
        )
      case _ => c.Expr[Seq[(String, Any)]](q"Seq.empty")
    }
```

So now I decide to return a String representation (but you can manipulate it as you want):

```
val elements = seqToExprs(accessorValues)
c.Expr[String](q"${elements}.mkString")
```

You can use it as:

```
import Macros._
class A(val a : Int)
class B(val b : Int) extends A(b)
class C(val c: Int) extends B(c)
//println(typeToString[List[Set[List[Double]]]])
val c = new C(10)
println(accessors[C](c)) // prints (a, 10)(b, 10)(c, 10)
println(accessors[B](c)) // prints (a, 10)(b, 10)
println(accessors[A](c)) // prints (a, 10)
```

And, using your example:

```
// Your example:
  case class Person(name: String,
                    override val age: Int,
                    override val address: String
                   ) extends Details(age, address)

  class Details(val age: Int, val address: String)

  val person = Person("Alex", 33, "Europe")
  println(accessors[Details](person)) // prints (address,Europe)(age,33)
  println(accessors[Person](person)) // prints (address,Europe)(age,33)(name,Alex)
```

[Here](https://github.com/cric96/parent-accessors-example) there is a repository with the macro implemented.

Scala 3.0 introduce a safer and cleaner macro system, if you use it and you want to go further you can read these articles:

- [macros tips and tricks](https://softwaremill.com/scala-3-macros-tips-and-tricks/#:%7E:text=Scala%203%20offers%20two%20basic%20metaprogramming%20modes%3A%20inlines,inline%20summon%20%28looking%20up%20given%20%2F%20implicit%20values%29.)
- [short tutorial](https://blog.softwaremill.com/starting-with-scala-3-macros-a-short-tutorial-88e9d2b2584c)
- [another tutorial](https://lampepfl.github.io/scala3-macro-tutorial/docs/tutorial/quoted-code.html)